# Is there a way to determine Java version without seeing shell output?

Tags: java

I have a following problem.

I am executing an OS command line from within Oracle database that executes an external jar file with some parameters. I can't see shell output but I can connect with a different user to that same server through ssh/ftp and read files. There are multiple versions of Java on that server and I would like to see which one Oracle is using.  Is it possible?

And before you start - no,

```
java -version > out.txt
```

does not work. It prints Java version to console and creates an empty file.

Comment: Log in with the same credentials as your oracle would do and run java -version. Possibly check the %PATH% variable, JAVA_HOME, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version message gets printed to STDERR, not STDOUT.

If you're on linux/unix, try

```
java -version >& version.txt
```

instead

Comment: Thant's a neat trick. Does it just redirect stderr or stdout as well?

Answer (score 7):

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```

Comment: I think this is what the OP actually wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
robert@rm:~> java -version >  out.txt 2>&1 
robert@rm:~> cat out.txt 
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's odd, it prints the version to stderr. If the console is *nix, do this:

```
java -version > out.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume the server is Unix/Linux, if so try:

> java -version >out.txt 2>&1